# Prepaid SIM card with best data plan in Canada

Tags: budget, canada, cellphones

I'm travelling to Canada

Does anyone know which prepaid SIM card has the best data plan?

In term of data usage and 3G/4G coverage. I don't think I'm ging to need to call a lot so talk time/texting/etc. are just optional. The only thing I care is data, preferably 2GB with cheapest fee.

Comment: T-mobile's data plans work in Canada. $20 for 1GB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what the current Telco providers have for prepaid data plans (closest to 2GB):

- [Rogers](http://www.rogers.com/web/content/wireless-products/plans?cm_sp=wireless-_-pay_as_you_go-_-plans_banner#,Tabset1--2) offers 2GB on the Talk, Text and Internet 80. **$80.75/month. $0.04/mb**
- [Bell](http://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Cell_phone_plans/Prepaid_plans) offers 2GB on the Prepaid - 100MB with $50 add on. **$70.75/month. roughly $0.03/mb**
- [Chatr](https://www.chatrwireless.com/web/chatr.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=PlanBrowse) offers 1GB on the Canada-wide Talk & Text with $25 add on. **$60.00/month. $0.06/mb**
- [Telus](http://www.telus.com/en/bc/mobility/prepaid/plans/?INTCMP=Beta_PrepaidLanding_HeroCTA_SeePlans) offers 400MB on the Talk + Data + Messaging 40. **$40.00/month. $0.1/mb**
- [Fido](http://www.fido.ca/web/page/portal/Fido/PrepaidPlans/Addons?lang=en) offers 1GB on the The base Prepaid plan ($15.75) with a $30 add on. **$45.75/month. $0.04/mb**
- [Koodo](http://koodomobile.com/en/on/plansandboosters.shtml) offers 1GB on the The base Prepaid plan ($15.00) with a $30 add on. **$45.00/month. $0.04/mb**

Comment: This is a very through review of the prepaid plans however this is not what the OP asked -- he wanted data. There are data only plans, mostly sold as "ipad plan" or "tablet plan" or sometimes "mobile internet".

Comment: To ecnepsnai: thanks a lot for the compilation. I myself would never be able to get this list. To chx: thanks for the internet plan suggestion as well. But I think even though it's not imminent now, I guess I still need calling somehow, so I will personally choose Bell talk + 2GB data plan added on.

Answer (score 2):

[Bell](http://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Cell_phone_plans/Tablet_PC_data_plans/30_Day_Pass.tab) has a 30 day pass data plan which is $35 for 5GB of data. This is $0.007/MB. Very good value. Use a SIP talk and SMS. I use [Anveo](http://anveo.com), it gives you  Canadian numbers that can receive SMS -- you will get them in email. And can send SMS via email, too.

[Wind Mobile](https://www.windmobile.ca/plans-and-devices/plans/mobile-plan-details/phone-plan-wind-35) will give you an unlimited data/text/talk plan for $35 (for more details consult the quick compare chart on the linked page) but if you go above 5GB you will be throttled. You need an AWS capable phone, there is no LTE and the coverage especially inside highrises is weaker. Wind calls prepaid "Pay Before". They also have a [Mobile Internet Plan](http://www.windmobile.ca/plans-and-devices/plans/mobile-internet-plan-details/Mobile-Internet-Plan-25) which is only $25 for 3GB and $35 for Unlimited which is again 5GB, really.

I would go with the Bell plan if I were you or if you are really short on money then perhaps the $25 for 3GB on Wind if my device would support it. (But then again I would rather skip going to Starbucks twice to save $10.)

Comment: In terms of a Canadian number, the iOS App called Free Tone gives you a Canadian number which you can receive/send texts from within the app.